# how to use firebase dynamic security?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm trying secure a chatbox for groups of two users. The goal is to make sure each group only access their own chat information, and no one can use the frontend code to see other groups info.

The firebase structure

```
root
  chat
    54a490ab6e13cca1d47870d6(this is group 1): 
      -2h8394hgorsnghrlnd
          from: 
          name: 
          text: 
      -fsdyf98yfoheifhwef
          from: 
          name: 
          text: 

    54ca2c11d1afc1612871624a(this is group 2)
      -Jh9W57FxfNPgsV2Ft_L
          from: 
          name: 
          text: 
      -Jh9W_6oSOLmP21o7K3l
          from: 
          name: 
          text:
```

Security rules has it [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/path.html), that there's a dynamic $location. But it uses "$user == auth.uid" stuff. I'm not planing to do any `uid` at all for the fronend.

```
{
    "rules": {
      "users": {
        "$user": {
          ".read": "$user == auth.uid",
          ".write": "$user == auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Is it possible to assign `group id"`  such as "54ca2c11d1afc1612871624a" to the security rules ?** or if it doesn't make sense, how can i make sure each group only access their own infomation?

Comment: When you say "their own information" it implies that you have the concept of a "current user" in the application. And in Firebase's security rules that current user maps to `auth`. If you don't want to use any of Firebase's standard authentication providers (Facebook, Google, Github, etc) then you can provide your own. But unless you somehow identify the current user to Firebase, there is no way to build security rules that limit what that user can access.

Comment: To compliment Frank's answer: if you already have a group id, and you've already verified the user is a part of that group, you can [sign your own tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html#section-custom), putting the group id into the user's auth token in any form you choose, and utilizing that for access.

Comment: thanks Kato. Looking into it. Why don't you guys just type the answers into the answer area?